# Is there any software which can distribute the internet speed to the programs according to their priority order?

Tags: windows, internet, utility, connection-speed

So, if first (assigned) process gets the internet speed first and after it's demand is over/fulfilled the remaining speed goes to second process and so on?

Comment: Take a look at QoS - although it is typically either host based (this computer on the LAN gets more bandwidth if there is contention) or protocol/port based (streaming video gets more bandwidth if there is contention)

Comment: Hello, I can't imagine a program that can detect program's demand is over/fulfilled but some schedulers can be done with NetLimiter or its alternatives.

Comment: Is your os Windows?

Comment: @onurcano22 it is.